# Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes

Tags: python, equality, equivalence

When writing custom classes it is often important to allow equivalence by means of the `==` and `!=` operators. In Python, this is made possible by implementing the `__eq__` and `__ne__` special methods, respectively. The easiest way I've found to do this is the following method:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Do you know of more elegant means of doing this? Do you know of any particular disadvantages to using the above method of comparing `__dict__`s?

**Note**: A bit of clarification--when `__eq__` and `__ne__` are undefined, you'll find this behavior:

```
>>> a = Foo(1)
>>> b = Foo(1)
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
False
```

That is, `a == b` evaluates to `False` because it really runs `a is b`, a test of identity (i.e., "Is `a` the same object as `b`?").

When `__eq__` and `__ne__` are defined, you'll find this behavior (which is the one we're after):

```
>>> a = Foo(1)
>>> b = Foo(1)
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```

Comment: +1, because I didn't know that dict used memberwise equality for ==, I had assumed it only counted them equal for same object dicts.  I guess this is obvious since Python has the `is` operator to distinguish object identity from value comparison.

Comment: I think the accepted answer be corrected or reassigned to Algorias' answer, so that the strict type check is implemented.

Comment: Also make sure hash is overridden http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608842/types-that-define-eq-are-unhashable-in-python-3-x

Comment: In 2022, use python3 and use @dataclass and everything just works.

Answer (score 470, accepted):

Consider this simple problem:

```
class Number:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number


n1 = Number(1)
n2 = Number(1)

n1 == n2 # False -- oops
```

So, Python by default uses the object identifiers for comparison operations:

```
id(n1) # 140400634555856
id(n2) # 140400634555920
```

Overriding the `__eq__` function seems to solve the problem:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    """Overrides the default implementation"""
    if isinstance(other, Number):
        return self.number == other.number
    return False


n1 == n2 # True
n1 != n2 # True in Python 2 -- oops, False in Python 3
```

In *Python 2*, always remember to override the `__ne__` function as well, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) states:

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The
>   truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when
>   defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the
>   operators will behave as expected.

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    """Overrides the default implementation (unnecessary in Python 3)"""
    return not self.__eq__(other)


n1 == n2 # True
n1 != n2 # False
```

In *Python 3*, this is no longer necessary, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) states:

> By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result
>   unless it is `NotImplemented`. There are no other implied
>   relationships among the comparison operators, for example, the truth
>   of `(x<y or x==y)` does not imply `x<=y`.

But that does not solve all our problems. Let’s add a subclass:

```
class SubNumber(Number):
    pass


n3 = SubNumber(1)

n1 == n3 # False for classic-style classes -- oops, True for new-style classes
n3 == n1 # True
n1 != n3 # True for classic-style classes -- oops, False for new-style classes
n3 != n1 # False
```

**Note:** Python 2 has two kinds of classes:

- *[classic-style](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)* (or *old-style*) classes, that do *not* inherit from `object` and that are declared as `class A:`, `class A():` or `class A(B):` where `B` is a classic-style class;
- *[new-style](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes)* classes, that do inherit from `object` and that are declared as `class A(object)` or `class A(B):` where `B` is a new-style class. Python 3 has only new-style classes that are declared as `class A:`, `class A(object):` or `class A(B):`.

For classic-style classes, a comparison operation always calls the method of the first operand, while for new-style classes, it always calls the method of the subclass operand, [regardless of the order of the operands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984987/78234).

So here, if `Number` is a classic-style class:

- `n1 == n3` calls `n1.__eq__`;
- `n3 == n1` calls `n3.__eq__`;
- `n1 != n3` calls `n1.__ne__`;
- `n3 != n1` calls `n3.__ne__`.

And if `Number` is a new-style class:

- both `n1 == n3` and `n3 == n1` call `n3.__eq__`;
- both `n1 != n3` and `n3 != n1` call `n3.__ne__`.

To fix the non-commutativity issue of the `==` and `!=` operators for Python 2 classic-style classes, the `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods should return the `NotImplemented` value when an operand type is not supported. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) defines the `NotImplemented` value as:

> Numeric methods and rich comparison methods may return this value if
>   they do not implement the operation for the operands provided. (The
>   interpreter will then try the reflected operation, or some other
>   fallback, depending on the operator.) Its truth value is true.

In this case the operator delegates the comparison operation to the *reflected method* of the *other* operand. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) defines reflected methods as:

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used
>   when the left argument does not support the operation but the right
>   argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s
>   reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and
>   `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection.

The result looks like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    """Overrides the default implementation"""
    if isinstance(other, Number):
        return self.number == other.number
    return NotImplemented

def __ne__(self, other):
    """Overrides the default implementation (unnecessary in Python 3)"""
    x = self.__eq__(other)
    if x is NotImplemented:
        return NotImplemented
    return not x
```

Returning the `NotImplemented` value instead of `False` is the right thing to do even for new-style classes if *commutativity* of the `==` and `!=` operators is desired when the operands are of unrelated types (no inheritance).

Are we there yet? Not quite. How many unique numbers do we have?

```
len(set([n1, n2, n3])) # 3 -- oops
```

Sets use the hashes of objects, and by default Python returns the hash of the identifier of the object. Let’s try to override it:

```
def __hash__(self):
    """Overrides the default implementation"""
    return hash(tuple(sorted(self.__dict__.items())))

len(set([n1, n2, n3])) # 1
```

The end result looks like this (I added some assertions at the end for validation):

```
class Number:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Overrides the default implementation"""
        if isinstance(other, Number):
            return self.number == other.number
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        """Overrides the default implementation (unnecessary in Python 3)"""
        x = self.__eq__(other)
        if x is not NotImplemented:
            return not x
        return NotImplemented

    def __hash__(self):
        """Overrides the default implementation"""
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.__dict__.items())))


class SubNumber(Number):
    pass


n1 = Number(1)
n2 = Number(1)
n3 = SubNumber(1)
n4 = SubNumber(4)

assert n1 == n2
assert n2 == n1
assert not n1 != n2
assert not n2 != n1

assert n1 == n3
assert n3 == n1
assert not n1 != n3
assert not n3 != n1

assert not n1 == n4
assert not n4 == n1
assert n1 != n4
assert n4 != n1

assert len(set([n1, n2, n3, ])) == 1
assert len(set([n1, n2, n3, n4])) == 2
```

Comment: `hash(tuple(sorted(self.__dict__.items())))` won't work if there are any non-hashable objects among the values of the `self.__dict__` (i.e., if any of the attributes of the object is set to, say, a `list`).

Comment: True, but then if you have such mutable objects in your vars() the two objects are not really equal...

Comment: Great summary, but you [should implement `__ne__` using `==` instead of `__eq__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676267/857390).

Comment: Three remarks: 1. In Python 3, no need to implement `__ne__` anymore: "By default, `__ne__()` delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result unless it is `NotImplemented`". 2. If one still wants to implement `__ne__`, a more generic implementation (the one used by Python 3 I think) is: `x = self.__eq__(other); if x is NotImplemented: return x; else: return not x`. 3. The given `__eq__` and `__ne__` implementations are suboptimal: `if isinstance(other, type(self)):` gives 22 `__eq__` and 10 `__ne__` calls, while `if isinstance(self, type(other)):` would give 16 `__eq__` and 6 `__ne__` calls.

Comment: While this answer eventually reaches a correct implementation, it gets there in a very confusing way. It repeatedly shows wrong code in a way that invites readers to think their problems are solved and stop reading, and it says the other answers don't work and then launches into a description of problems other answers *do* handle before getting to the parts they don't. Also, it doesn't mention the cases where you should set `__hash__` to `None` instead of implementing it.

Comment: The isinstance(other, ...) check was super helpful for dealing with checks against None. Thanks!

Comment: He asked about elegance, but he got robust.

Comment: `n1 == n3` should also be `True` even for classic class? Because this case `other` should be `n3` and `isinstance(n3, Number)` is True?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 232):

You need to be careful with inheritance:

```
>>> class Foo:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return False

>>> class Bar(Foo):pass

>>> b = Bar()
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f == b
True
>>> b == f
False
```

Check types more strictly, like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if type(other) is type(self):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
    return False
```

Besides that, your approach will work fine, that's what special methods are there for.

Comment: This is a good point. I suppose it's worth noting that sub-classing built in types still allows for equality either direction, and so checking that it's the same type may even be undesirable.

Comment: I'd suggest to return NotImplemented if the types are different, delegating the comparison to the rhs.

Comment: @max comparison isn't necessarily done left hand side (LHS) to right hand side (RHS), then RHS to LHS; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12984987/38140. Still, returning `NotImplemented` as you suggest will always cause `superclass.__eq__(subclass)`, which is the desired behavior.

Comment: this is faster too, because isinstance can be a bit slow

Comment: If you have a ton of members, and not many object copies sitting around, then it's usually good add an initial an identity test `if other is self`. This avoids the more lengthy dictionary comparison, and can be a huge savings when objects are used as dictionary keys.

Comment: And don't forget to implement `__hash__()`

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, because it actually answer the specific question about \_\_dict\_\_.

Comment: It's important to note that for equality to be true, objects don't necessarily need to be the same type. For instance, one can argue that a linked list with the same elements as an array-backed list are in fact equal.

Answer (score 165):

The way you describe is the way I've always done it. Since it's totally generic, you can always break that functionality out into a mixin class and inherit it in classes where you want that functionality.

```
class CommonEqualityMixin(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (isinstance(other, self.__class__)
            and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

class Foo(CommonEqualityMixin):

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
```

Comment: +1: Strategy pattern to allow easy replacement in subclasses.

Comment: isinstance sucks. Why check it? Why not just self.__dict__ == other.__dict__?

Comment: @nosklo: I don't understand.. what if two objects from completely unrelated classes happen to have the same attributes?

Comment: @max nosklo makes a good point. Consider the default behavior when sub-classing the built in objects. The `==` operator does not care if you compare a built-in to a sub-class of the built-in.

Comment: I thought nokslo suggested skipping isinstance. In that case you no longer know if `other` is of a subclass of `self.__class__`.

Comment: @max: yeah, but it doesn't matter if it is a subclass or not. It is irrelevant information. Consider what will happen if it is not a subclass.

Comment: @nosklo: if it's not subclass, but it just happens by accident to have same attributes as `self` (both keys and values), `__eq__` might evaluate to `True`, even though it's meaningless. Do I miss anything?

Comment: @nosklo: Yeah, maybe `hasattr(other, '__dict__') and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__` would be better in the general case. I guess I just prefer a stricter notion of equality, given the option.

Comment: Another issue with the `__dict__` comparison is what if you have an attribute that you don't want to consider in your definition of equality (say for example a unique object id, or metadata like a time created stamp).

Comment: @cdleary: I can see that `hasattr` would prevent an exception when `other` doesn't have `__dict__` (i.e., implemented with slots). But how is it related to @nosklo question?

Comment: i think implementing this in all your classes could lead to infinite recursion with circular references (e.g. set a.b = b, b.a = a, a==a)

Comment: Note that this has some issues with inheritance, be sure to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/390640/250880) solution as well!

Comment: Also, not adding the check to `hasattr(self, '__dict__')` will cause an exception when comparing to None. A pretty glaring hole in the implementation.

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Answer (score 18):

Not a direct answer but seemed relevant enough to be tacked on as it saves a bit of verbose tedium on occasion. Cut straight from the docs...

---

[functools.total_ordering(cls)](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

**Given a class defining one or more rich comparison ordering methods, this class decorator supplies the rest.** This simplifies the effort involved in specifying all of the possible rich comparison operations:

The class must define one of `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or `__ge__()`. In addition, the class should supply an `__eq__()` method.

New in version 2.7

```
@total_ordering
class Student:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return ((self.lastname.lower(), self.firstname.lower()) ==
                (other.lastname.lower(), other.firstname.lower()))
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return ((self.lastname.lower(), self.firstname.lower()) <
                (other.lastname.lower(), other.firstname.lower()))
```

Comment: However total_ordering has subtle pitfalls: https://regebro.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/python-implementing-rich-comparison-the-correct-way/. Be aware !

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to override both `__eq__` and `__ne__` you can override only `__cmp__` but this will make an implication on the result of ==, !==, < , > and so on.

`is` tests for object identity. This means a `is` b will be `True` in the case when a and b both hold the reference to the same object. In python you always hold a reference to an object in a variable not the actual object, so essentially for a is b to be true the objects in them should be located in the same memory location. How and most importantly why would you go about overriding this behaviour?

Edit: I didn't know `__cmp__` was removed from python 3 so avoid it.

Comment: Because sometimes you have a different definition of equality for your objects.

Comment: the is operator gives you the interpreters answer to object identity, but you are still free to express you view on equality by overriding __cmp__

Comment: In Python 3, "The cmp() function is gone, and the __cmp__() special method is no longer supported." http://is.gd/aeGv

Answer (score 6):

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676267/541136 I have demonstrated that, while it's correct to define `__ne__` in terms `__eq__` - instead of

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

you should use:

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self == other
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that the two terms you're looking for are **equality** (==) and **identity** (is). For example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a == b
True       <-- a and b have values which are equal
>>> a is b
False      <-- a and b are not the same list object
```

Comment: Maybe, except that one can create a class that only compares the first two items in two lists, and if those items are equal, it evaluates to True. This is equivalence, I think, not equality. Perfectly valid in __eq__, still.

Comment: I do agree, however, that "is" is a test of identity.

Answer (score 3):

The 'is' test will test for identity using the builtin 'id()' function which essentially returns the memory address of the object and therefore isn't overloadable.

However in the case of testing the equality of a class you probably want to be a little bit more strict about your tests and only compare the data attributes in your class:

```
import types

class ComparesNicely(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
            if (isinstance(value, types.FunctionType) or 
                    key.startswith("__")):
                continue

            if key not in other.__dict__:
                return False

            if other.__dict__[key] != value:
                return False

         return True
```

This code will only compare non function data members of your class as well as skipping anything private which is generally what you want. In the case of Plain Old Python Objects I have a base class which implements __init__, __str__, __repr__ and __eq__ so my POPO objects don't carry the burden of all that extra (and in most cases identical) logic.

Comment: Bit nitpicky, but 'is' tests using id() only if you haven't defined your own is_() member function (2.3+). [http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html]

Comment: I assume by "override" you actually mean monkey-patching the operator module. In this case your statement is not entirely accurate. The operators module is provided for convenience and overriding those methods does not affect the behavior of the "is" operator. A comparison using "is" always uses the id() of an object for the comparison, this behavior can not be overridden. Also an is_ member function has no effect on the comparison.

Comment: mcrute - I spoke too soon (and incorrectly), you are absolutely right.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, especially when the `__eq__` will be declared in `CommonEqualityMixin` (see the other answer). I found this particularly useful when comparing instances of classes derived from Base in SQLAlchemy. To not compare `_sa_instance_state` I changed `key.startswith("__")):` to `key.startswith("_")):`. I had also some backreferences in them and the answer from Algorias generated endless recursion. So I named all  backreferences starting with `'_'` so that they're also skipped during comparison. NOTE: in Python 3.x change `iteritems()` to `items()`.

Comment: @mcrute Usually, `__dict__` of an instance doesn't have anything that starts with `__` unless it was defined by the user. Things like `__class__`, `__init__`, etc. are not in the instance's `__dict__`, but rather in its class' `__dict__`. OTOH, the private attributes can easily start with `__` and probably should be used for `__eq__`. Can you clarify what exactly were you trying to avoid when skipping `__`-prefixed attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using subclassing/mixins, I like to use a generic class decorator

```
def comparable(cls):
    """ Class decorator providing generic comparison functionality """

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    cls.__eq__ = __eq__
    cls.__ne__ = __ne__
    return cls
```

Usage:

```
@comparable
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a = Number(1)
b = Number(1)
assert a == b
```

Answer (score 2):

This incorporates the comments on Algorias' answer, and compares objects by a single attribute because I don't care about the whole dict. `hasattr(other, "id")` must be true, but I know it is because I set it in the constructor.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if other is self:
        return True

    if type(other) is not type(self):
        # delegate to superclass
        return NotImplemented

    return other.id == self.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Another elegant way of supporting equivalences, is to use `@dataclass`. Your `Foo` example would then become:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Foo:
    item: int
```

That's it! Now the behaviour is as follows:

```
a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(1)
print(a == b)  # True
c = Foo(2)
print(a == c)  # False
```

If your class needs to provide other instance attributes, which should *not* play a role in the equivalence, then define them in `__post_init__`, like so:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from random import randint

@dataclass
class Foo:
    age: int
    name: str
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.rnd = randint(1, 100000)

a = Foo(38, "Helen")
b = Foo(38, "Helen")
print(a == b)  # True
print(a.rnd == b.rnd)  # False, probably ;-)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom base with a default implementation of `__ne__` that simply negates `__eq__`:

```py
class HasEq(object):
  """
  Mixin that provides a default implementation of ``object.__neq__`` using the subclass's implementation of ``object.__eq__``.

  This overcomes Python's deficiency of ``==`` and ``!=`` not being symmetric when overloading comparison operators
  (i.e. ``not x == y`` *does not* imply that ``x != y``), so whenever you implement
  `object.__eq__ <https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__>`_, it is expected that you
  also implement `object.__ne__ <https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__>`_

  NOTE: in Python 3+ this is no longer necessary (see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__)
  """

  def __ne__(self, other):
    """
    Default implementation of ``object.__ne__(self, other)``, delegating to ``self.__eq__(self, other)``.

    When overriding ``object.__eq__`` in Python, one should also override ``object.__ne__`` to ensure that
    ``not x == y`` is the same as ``x != y``
    (see `object.__eq__ <https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__>`_ spec)

    :return: ``NotImplemented`` if ``self.__eq__(other)`` returns ``NotImplemented``, otherwise ``not self.__eq__(other)``
    """
    equal = self.__eq__(other)
    # the above result could be either True, False, or NotImplemented
    if equal is NotImplemented:
      return NotImplemented
    return not equal
```

If you inherit from this base class, you only have to implement `__eq__` and the base.

In retrospect, a better approach might have been to implement it as a decorator instead.  Something like [`@functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)