# Types that define `__eq__` are unhashable?

Tags: python, hash, python-3.x

I had a strange bug when porting a feature to the Python 3.1 fork of my program. I narrowed it down to the following hypothesis:

In contrast to Python 2.x, in Python 3.x if an object has an `__eq__` method it is automatically unhashable.

Is this true?

Here's what happens in Python 3.1:

```
>>> class O(object):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return 'whatever'
...
>>> o = O()
>>> d = {o: 0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    d = {o: 0}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'O'
```

The follow-up question is, how do I solve my personal problem? I have an object `ChangeTracker` which stores a `WeakKeyDictionary` that points to several objects, giving for each the value of their pickle dump at a certain time point in the past. Whenever an existing object is checked in, the change tracker says whether its new pickle is identical to its old one, therefore saying whether the object has changed in the meantime. Problem is, now I can't even check if the given object is in the library, because it makes it raise an exception about the object being unhashable. (Cause it has a `__eq__` method.) How can I work around this?

Comment: What happens if you provide a `__hash__` method?

Comment: I'm surprised to see nobody is discussing around why this is not a problem for Python 2.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Yes, if you define `__eq__`, the default `__hash__` (namely, hashing the address of the object in memory) goes away. This is important because hashing needs to be consistent with equality: equal objects need to hash the same.

The solution is simple: just define `__hash__` along with defining `__eq__`.

Comment: Let me add for posterity: I defined `__hash__` as `return id(self)`.

Comment: @cool-RR: Use of `id(self)` in `__hash__()` in certainly wrong unless you defined `__eq__()` to compare by object identity (which seems meaningless). What about updating your question with real `__eq__()` implementation so that we could suggest `__hash__()` complementing it?

Comment: I've been trying to solve this issue as well; I came up with this: `def __eq__(): return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__ ` and  `def __hash__(): return hash(self.__dict__.values())`

Comment: This is not a good answer - it's not just the default hash that goes away - it's _any inherited hash_.

Answer (score 33):

This paragraph from [http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

> If a class that overrides `__eq__()`
>   needs to retain the implementation of
>   `__hash__()` from a parent class, the interpreter must be told this
>   explicitly by setting `__hash__ =
>   <ParentClass>.__hash__`. Otherwise the
>   inheritance of `__hash__()` will be
>   blocked, just as if `__hash__` had been
>   explicitly set to None.

Comment: So would this be `def __hash__ (self): return <ParentClass>.__hash__` ? I don't manage to make it work, nor I found any example online.

Comment: @JesusMartinezGarcia: You have to write the line `__hash__ = <ParentClass>.__hash__` inside the class definition (instead of defining a method with `def`), or alternately you can do `def __hash__(self): return <ParentClass>.__hash__(self)`

Comment: I've tried both of those things and I get an error.
First suggestion:  
`__hash__ = <ParentClass>.__hash__  
               ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  
Second suggestion:  
`File "<string>", line 24  
    return <ParentClass>.__hash__(self)  
               ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

(I don't manage to put the breaks in the right place, but essentially the arrow is pointing to the '<' in front of ParentClass)

Comment: @JesusMartinezGarcia: It doesn't mean to literally put `<ParentClass>`, but to put the name of the parent class there

Comment: Oh, dear. I didn't realise of this, which it now feels obvious. Thanks for pointing it out. I thought <ParentClass> would automatically call the parent class but I understand now it cannot since self is not even specified. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 8):

Check the Python 3 manual on [`object.__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=hash#object.__hash__):

> If a class does not define an `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; **if it defines `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections.**

Emphasis is mine.

If you want to be lazy, it sounds like you can just define `__hash__(self)` to return `id(self)`:

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns `id(x)`.

Comment: Surely the only reason to overload the equals operator is because two different objects can sometimes compare equal (if not then don't bother overloading it). In this case the `return id(self)` hash function is broken (equal objects must hash the same, see Martin's answer). The "I don't care" hash function would be `return 1`. This is simple and satisfies all the conditions (it's just very inefficient!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no python expert, but wouldn't it make sense that, when you define a eq-method, you also have to define a hash-method as well (which calculates the hash value for an object) Otherwise, the hashing mechanism wouldn't know if it hit the same object, or a different object with just the same hash-value. Actually, it's the other way around, it'd probably end up computing different hash values for objects considered equal by your `__eq__` method.

I have no idea what that hash function is called though, `__hash__` perhaps? :)

Comment: FYI: I drew this sometime ago (http://www.mindmeister.com/10510492/python-underscore): a mindmap of all the underscore methods in python.

Comment: It's actually vice versa. If two objects have the same hash value, but are not equal - that's fine. The "hashing mechanism" (i.e. the dictionary) first checks the hash, and, on same hash, also compares for equality. The real problem occurs the other way 'round: objects hash differently but still compare the same. The dictionary should find them, but doesn't (or you may get duplicate keys in the dictionary).

Comment: @Martin v. Löwis: I realized that, and added that at the end, or is there a subtle difference to what I said?