# Why does a successful assertEqual not always imply a successful assertItemsEqual?

Tags: python, python-unittest

The [Python 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertItemsEqual) state that `assertItemsEqual` "is the equivalent of `assertEqual(sorted(expected), sorted(actual))`".  In the below example, all tests pass except for test4.  Why does `assertItemsEqual` fail in this case?

Per the principle of least astonishment, given two iterables, I would expect that a successful `assertEqual` implies a successful `assertItemsEqual`.

```
import unittest

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a

class test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.list1 = [foo(1), foo(2)]
        self.list2 = [foo(1), foo(2)]

    def test1(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.list1 == self.list2)

    def test2(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.list1, self.list2)

    def test3(self):
        self.assertEqual(sorted(self.list1), sorted(self.list2))

    def test4(self):
        self.assertItemsEqual(self.list1, self.list2)

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is the output on my machine:

```
FAIL: test4 (__main__.test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assert_test.py", line 25, in test4
    self.assertItemsEqual(self.list1, self.list2)
AssertionError: Element counts were not equal:
First has 1, Second has 0:  <__main__.foo object at 0x7f67b3ce2590>
First has 1, Second has 0:  <__main__.foo object at 0x7f67b3ce25d0>
First has 0, Second has 1:  <__main__.foo object at 0x7f67b3ce2610>
First has 0, Second has 1:  <__main__.foo object at 0x7f67b3ce2650>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Because you haven't defined an ordering on `foo` objects?

Comment: Thanks.  To your point, test4 passes if I define a __hash__ method on `foo`.  However, the docs state that assertItemsEqual works on unhashable objects.  Am I misunderstanding the doc?

Comment: I don't know Python very well, but the error message is clearly telling you that it's comparing the lists by counting unique objects in both and then comparing the counts key by key.  The comparisons are by object address. Since you have different object instances in each list, the lists compare as not equal.  If you said `a = foo(1); b = foo(2); self.list1 = [a, b]
self.list2 = [b, a]`, I bet the last test would pass.

Comment: It works on unhashable objects based on object address (the address always allows a hash)!

Comment: Thanks, Gene.  Yes, the tests would pass for your modified example.  The point of my question is that the docs seem unclear (at least to me)---they seem to imply that assertEqual(sorted(actual), sorted(expected)) is equivalent to assertItemsEqual(actual, expected), even for unhashable objects.

Comment: Another point: docs for `assertEqual` stands about equal elements (*Test that first and second are equal*), while docs for `assertItemsEqual` says about *same* elements (_Test that sequence expected contains **the same elements as actual**, regardless of their order_). Seems very unclear to me too.

Comment: By the way, I don't think python can make any guarantee that your `test3` should pass either - so it might just be luck/implementation detail

Comment: I absolutely love this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document spec is interestingly detached from the implementation, which never does any sorting. [Here is the source code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/python/pypy/lib-python/2.7/unittest/case.py#863).  As you can see, it first tries to count by hashing using `collections.Counter`. If this fails with a type error (because either list contains an item that's unhashable), it moves on to [a second algorithm](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/python/jython/lib-python/2.7/unittest/util.py#100), where it compares using python `==` and O(n^2) loops.

So if your `foo` class were unhashable, the second algorithm would signal a match. But it is perfectly hashable.  From the docs:

> Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their id().

I verified this by calling `collections.Counter([foo(1)])`. No type error exception.

So here is where your code comes off the rails. From the docs on `__hash__`:

> if it defines **cmp**() or **eq**() but not **hash**(), its instances will not be usable in hashed collections.

Unfortunately "not usable" apparently does not equate to "unhashable."

It goes on to say:

> Classes which inherit a **hash**() method from a parent class but change the meaning of **cmp**() or **eq**() such that the hash value returned is no longer appropriate (e.g. by switching to a value-based concept of equality instead of the default identity based equality) can explicitly flag themselves as being unhashable by setting **hash** = None in the class definition.

If we redefine:

```
class foo(object):
    __hash__ = None
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, foo) and self.a == other.a
```

all tests pass!

So it appears the documents are not exactly wrong, but they're not abundantly clear either. They ought to mention that counting is done with hashing and only if that fails is simple equality matching tried. This is only a valid approach if the objects have either complete hashing semantics or are completely unhashable. Yours were in the middle ground. (I believe Python 3 is more rigorous about disallowing or at least warning against classes of this type.)

Comment: Thank you, Gene. Your response is clearly written and explains the root cause---I particularly appreciate that you grounded your answer in the Python source code.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a nicely written question. The next interesting thing is that I tried setting `__hash__ = None` as recommended for user classes setting `__eq__` but not `__hash__`. Sure enough, the second algorithm runs because this makes `foo` unhashable. But apparently it has a bug! I get an exception, field `a` does not exist. There's a bogus object being compared. I need to get some sleep. Have fun with it.

Comment: @MatthewNizol I figured out what was going on. The second algorithm works by writing references to a NULL object over already-compared ones. Your `__eq__` was failing on these refs because NULL had no `a` field. I fixed it in the code above. Good night!

Answer (score 3):

The relevant part of the docs is here:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ordering#not-in

> Most other objects of built-in types compare unequal unless they are the same object; the choice whether one object is considered smaller or larger than another one is made arbitrarily but consistently within one execution of a program.

So if you make `x, y = foo(1), foo(1)`, then it's not well-defined whether the ordering ends up as `x > y` or `x < y`.  In python3 you would not be allowed at all, the `sorted` call should raise an exception.

Since unittest calls `setUp` for each and every test method, you get different `foo` instances created each time.

---

`assertItemsEqual` is implemented with a `collections.Counter` (a subclass of dict), so I think the failure of `test4` may be a symptom of this fact:

```
>>> x, y = foo(1), foo(1)
>>> x == y
True
>>> {x: None} == {y: None}
False
```

***If two items compare equal, then they should hash the same,*** otherwise you risk breaking mappings like this.

Comment: Thanks, wim.  I see your point that the sorted() call might produce undefined behavior.  However, I tested the behavior after adding a __cmp__ method to foo (return -1 if self.a < other.a, 0 if self.a == other.a, and 1 if self.a > other.a), and test4 still fails.  Test4 does succeed if I add a __hash__ method (returning self.a); so it appears that assertItemEqual is grouping based on the hash value.  The docs don't appear to state that requirement, however.

Comment: I think that's because `assertItemsEqual` is implemented with a `collections.Counter`.  Interesting.  Let me investigate further ..

Comment: Thank you very much for the research.  You came to the same conclusion that Gene did---that the root cause is the use of `collections.Counter` in the implementation.  However, because I can only accept 1 answer, I accepted Gene's due to his additional observation that all user-defined objects are hashable by default via their id(), which clarifies why `collections.Counter` groups the foo instances as it does.  Thank you again!

Comment: this fishy behaviour appears to be fixed in python3.  related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1608842/674039

Comment: specifically, see the comment from martin here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608842/types-that-define-eq-are-unhashable-in-python-3-x#comment1474489_1608865