# Is it really necessary to hash the same for classes that compare the same?

Tags: python, class, hash, equivalence

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608882/143211) it seems, that if `__eq__` is defined in custom class, `__hash__` needs to be defined as well. This is understandable.
However it is not clear, why - effectively - `__eq__` should be same as `self.__hash__()==other.__hash__`

Imagining a class like this:

```
class Foo:
    ...
    self.Name
    self.Value
    ...
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.Value==other.Value
    ...
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.Name)
```

This way class instances could be compared by value, which could be the only reasonable use, but considered identical by name.
This way `set` could not contain multiple instances with equal name, but comparison would still work.

What could be the problem with such definition?

The reason for defining `__eq__`, `__lt__` and other by `Value` is to be able to sort instances by `Value` and to be able to use functions like max. For example, he class should represent a physical output of a device (say heating element). Each of these outputs has unique Name. The Value is power of the output device. To find optimal combination of heating elements to turn on, it is useful to be able to compare them by power (Value). In a set or dictionary, however, it should not be possible to have multiple outputs with same names. Of course, different outputs with different names might easily have equal power.

Comment: If it's `Value` that's important for equality, you'd generally implement `__hash__` as `return hash(self.Value)`.

Comment: In this case Value is not enough for identity, only for size. Defining it __eq_ by value along with _lt_ and others is way to allow the class to be sortable by value, but instances with same value are not considered identical.

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? At the moment the problem seems to be that your class isn't consistently defined.

Comment: I updated the question with specific example, hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: In your case, I'd suggest equality would be purely on value and hash on name and value (`return hash(self.Name) ^ hash(self.Value)`. *"equal objects need to hash the same"* is a bit of a simplification, rather *identical* objects should hash the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that it does not make sense, hash is used to do efficient bucketing of objects. Consequently, when you have a set, which is implemented as a hash table, each hash points to a bucket, which is usually a list of elements. In order to check if an element is in the set (or other hash based container) you go to the bucket pointed by a hash and then you iterate over all elements in the list, comparing them one by one.

In other words - hash is not supposed to be a comparator (as it can, and should give you sometimes a false positive). In particular, in your example, your set will not work - it will not recognize duplicate, as they do not compare to each other.

```
class Foo:

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.Value==other.Value

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.Name)


a = set()
el = Foo()
el.Name = 'x'
el.Value = 1

el2 = Foo()
el2.Name = 'x'
el2.Value = 2

a.add(el)
a.add(el2)
print len(a) # should be 1, right? Well it is 2
```

actually it is even worse then that, if you have 2 objects with the same values but different names, they are not recognized to be the same either

```
class Foo:

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.Value==other.Value

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.Name)


a = set()
el = Foo()
el.Name = 'x'
el.Value = 2

el2 = Foo()
el2.Name = 'a'
el2.Value = 2

a.add(el)
a.add(el2)
print len(a) # should be 1, right? Well it is 2 again
```

while doing it properly (thus, "if a == b, then hash(a) == hash(b)") gives:

```
class Foo:

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.Name==other.Name

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.Name)


a = set()
el = Foo()
el.Name = 'x'
el.Value = 1

el2 = Foo()
el2.Name = 'x'
el2.Value = 2

a.add(el)
a.add(el2)
print len(a) # is really 1
```

## Update

There is also an non deterministic part, which is hard to easily reproduce, but essentially hash does not uniquely define a bucket. Usually it is like

```
bucket_id = hash(object) % size_of_allocated_memory
```

consequently things that have different hashes can still end up in the same bucket. Consequently, you can get two elements equal to each (inside set) due to equality of Values even though Names are different, as well as the other way around, depending on actual internal implementation, memory constraints etc.

In general there are many more examples where things can go wrong, as hash is **defined** as a function `h : X -> Z` such that `x == y => h(x) == h(y)`, thus people implementing their containers, authorization protocols, and other tools are free to **assume** this property. If you break it - every single tool using hashes can break. Furthermore, it can break **in time**, meaning that you update some library and your code will stop working, as a valid update to the underlying libraries (using the above assumption) can lead to exploiting your violation of this assumption.

## Update 2

Finally, in order to solve your issue - you simply should not define your **eq**, **lt** operators to handle sorting. It is about **actual comparison of the elements**, which should be compatible with the rest of the behaviours. All you have to do is define a separate **comparator** and use it in your sorting routines (sorting in python accepts any comparator, you do not need to rely on <, > etc.). The other way around is to instead have valid <, >, = defined on values, but in order to keep names unique - keep a set with... well... names, and not objects themselves. Whichever path you choose - the crucial element here is:
**equality and hashing have to be compatible**, that's all.

Comment: The first behavior you described is exactly what i would like to have.

Comment: It is a bit tricky to show an example when it blows up, but you can have actually a different names, that will be placed in the same bucket, and then you will get a false positive due to values being equal. The fact that "id" should be unique does not mean that actual buckets will be unique. In other words - first example is **non deterministic**. It will sometimes give you equal elements and sometimes not. Depending of the internal implementation of python interpreter, available memory etc.

Comment: @Lukas Now you're contradicting yourself. In the question, you wrote _"In a set or dicionary, however, it should not be possible to have multiple outputs with same names"_.

Comment: @Rawing: My mistake, it's the second i want, the first one should really be one.

Comment: And neither is 1 (and cannot be), as shown in the examples. The "second" behaviour requires fixing hash to the original definition (thus my last example)

Comment: I have a set with names anyway, and for the classes itself a list can be used.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to implement your class like this and *not* have any problems. However, you have to be 100% sure that no two different objects will ever produce the same hash. Consider the following example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name= name
        self.value= value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name[0])

s= set()
s.add(Foo('a', 1))
s.add(Foo('b', 1))
print(len(s)) # output: 2
```

But you have a problem if a hash collision occurs:

```
s.add(Foo('abc', 1))
print(len(s)) # output: 2
```

In order to prevent this, you would have to know **exactly** how the hashes are generated (which, if you rely on functions like `id` or `hash`, might vary between implementations!) and also the values of the attribute(s) used to generate the hash (`name` in this example). That's why ruling out the possibility of a hash collision is very difficult, if not impossible. It's basically like begging for unexpected things to happen.

Comment: this is simply not true. Hash do not have to identify uniquely any bucket, hash-tables (and other containers) can (and do) take modulo operations (or other mapping to constant size containers) on your hash, consequently even two unique hashes can end up being bucketed in the same spot, and while this could be solved on the container level (you could compare the hash when iterating) there is no point of doing so, as "regular" equality is supposed to work

Comment: @lejlot So that means it's even harder to avoid hash collisions than I said. That doesn't mean what I said is wrong though.

Comment: this is not a hash collision. These are two different things. Hash collision is, as in your answer, when you have x!=y such that h(x)==h(y). What I am describing is a kind of error you might encounter when you use hashes in practise. These errors come from the fact, that (as said in previous answer) there is an underlying assumptin about hashing, that if two objects are equal their hashes are equal too. Period. This is not about colliding, it is about a common logic following hashing that may (and will, at some point) be broken.