# LRU cache unhashable type if subclass from Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lru

I am trying to figure out why the following code does not work

```
from functools import lru_cache
import numpy as np

class Mask(dict):
    def __init__(self, shape, data = None):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.shape = shape

    @lru_cache(maxsize=1)
    def tomatrix(self):
        dense = np.zeros(self.shape[0] * self.shape[1])
        for uid, entries in self.items():
            dense[entries] = uid
        return np.reshape(dense, self.shape)

cells = {i : np.arange(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10) for i in range(10)}
mask = Mask((10, 10), cells)

r1 = mask.tomatrix()
r2 = mask.tomatrix()
```

The error says

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Mask'
```

as if `lru_cache` tries to cache `self` in `self.tomatrix()`.

On the other hand, if I don't subclass from `dict` and instead have an internal member `self.data` that stores the actual data, the LRU wrapper does not complain.

Code that works:

```
from functools import lru_cache
import numpy as np

class Mask:
    def __init__(self, shape, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.shape = shape

    @lru_cache(maxsize=1)
    def tomatrix(self):
        dense = np.zeros(self.shape[0] * self.shape[1])
        for uid, entries in self.data.items():
            dense[entries] = uid
        return np.reshape(dense, self.shape)

cells = {i : np.arange(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10) for i in range(10)}
mask = Mask((10, 10), cells)

r1 = mask.tomatrix()
r2 = mask.tomatrix()
```

Anyone can help me figure out this mystery? I'd like to continue subclassing from `dict` and I need to use LRU caching.

Comment: I think I solved my own "mystery": subclassing from `dict` means inheriting `__eq__` which discards `__hash__` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608842/types-that-define-eq-are-unhashable)). The solution is to defined `__hash__` for `Mask(dict)`; the question is now how.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to get the default `__hash__` function defined for user classes that inherits from `object`. `dict` defines its own `__eq__`, but no `__hash__` which is therefore blocked.

Adding the line

```
__hash__ = object.__hash__
```

to `Mask(dict)` works.

Many thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608907/14737723) answer to another question!