# Problems with "F" and brackets

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand some of the syntaxes of the tutorial of matplotlib from Sentdex's video. For example, on Line 10, what is "F(container, self)" and what is F in this context? Same thing for Line 11 with "self.Frames[F]", what is F here and why are there square brackets on the left-hand side? Finally, same thing for Line 15, why is there square brackets for [cont]?

```
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):                                                                   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)

    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
```

Comment: `F` is your current item in your iteration of `(StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo)`

Comment: Then you are doing `StartPage(container, self)`, `PageOne(container, self)`, `PageTwo(container, self)`

Comment: although its weird to be using some class or whatever as a key into the dictionary ...

Answer (score 2):

Functions, classes, and instances of a class (objects) are all first class in Python. `F()` just calls `F`, which will throw an exception if `F` is not callable ([What is a "callable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable)).  The `[F]` is using `F` as a key in the dictionary self.frames (`[]` can be used in other ways as well:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-41) which will throw an exception unless `F` is hashable and supports an `__eq__` method.  Presumably all of StartPage, PageOne, and PageTwo are callable, hashable, and have an `__eq__` method.

Perhaps making the code more generic will help to clarify things:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class frame:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(f"frame initialized with {args}")
    def grid(self, **kwargs):
        print(f"frame.grid called with args: {kwargs}")


def StartPage(a=None, b=None):
    return frame(a, b)

class PageOne:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(f"PageOne initialized with {args}")
    def grid(self, **kwargs):
        print(f"PageOne.grid called with args: {kwargs}")

class C:
    def __call__(*args):
        return PageOne(args)

PageTwo = C()
container = None

frames = {}
for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
    frame = F(container, None)
    frames[F] = frame
    print( f"F is {F}")
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

The above code produces the output:

```
frame initialized with (None, None)
F is <function StartPage at 0x105c63f70>
frame.grid called with args: {'row': 0, 'column': 0, 'sticky': 'nsew'}
PageOne initialized with (None, None)
F is <class '__main__.PageOne'>
PageOne.grid called with args: {'row': 0, 'column': 0, 'sticky': 'nsew'}
PageOne initialized with ((<__main__.C object at 0x105e2a610>, None, None),)
F is <__main__.C object at 0x105e2a610>
PageOne.grid called with args: {'row': 0, 'column': 0, 'sticky': 'nsew'}
```

In this case, we iterate through the loop three times.  The first time in the loop, the name `F` is bound to the function `StartPage`.  Functions are callable; `F(container, None)` calls the function StartPage with those 2 arguments and binds `frame` to the object returned by that function call.  That object has a `grid` method, and `frame.grid()` calls it.  `StartPage` is hashable and supports an `__eq__` method, so it can be used as a key in the `frames` dictionary.  The 2nd time through the loop, the name `F` is cound to the class `PageOne`, and `F(container, None)` invokes the class's `__init__` method to create an object which is an instance of that class.  Again, that object is hashable and can be used as a key in the `frames` dictionary, and it contains a `grid` method.  3rd time through the loop, the name F is bound to the object `PageTwo`, which was previously initialized as an instance of class `C`.

In your case, all three objects in the iteration are probably instances of the same class, but I'm hoping the concrete example will help to clarify.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind and considerate help in "holding my hand" on this. However, I still have some questions from your explanation: 1. How is F a function when I didn't declare it a function beforehand like "def F():", I still think that F here acts as a loop counter though? 2. Why did PageTwo suddenly have three parameters initialized, one being its address when looping through the third time?   3. What does an __eq__ method have to do with getting called as a function? Sorry for my questions as I'm still a newbie here in Python.

Comment: `F` is simply a variable used as the loop index.  Each time through the loop, it takes a different value.   The first time through, the name `F` is bound to `StartPage`.  I don't know what the type of `StartPage` is in your code.  In my example, it is a function.  Object methods receive the object as a first parameter, so `AnObject.method(b,c)` calls the functions with `AnObject` as its first argument, and `b` and `c` as its 2nd and third arguments.  By convention, the first argument is usually named `self`.  The `__eq__` method is not related to functions.

Comment: `__eq__` is a technical detail: any object that is used as a key in a dictionary must support an `__eq__` method.  You can read more about that at https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608842/types-that-define-eq-are-unhashable and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-does-hashable-mean-in-python