# Python: Is this an ok way of overriding __eq__ and __hash__?

Tags: python, hash

I'm new to Python, and I wanted to make sure that I overrode `__eq__` and `__hash__` correctly, so as not to cause painful errors later:

(I'm using Google App Engine.)

```
class Course(db.Model):
    dept_code = db.StringProperty()
    number = db.IntegerProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    raw_pre_reqs = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    original_description = db.StringProperty()

    def getPreReqs(self):
        return pickle.loads(str(self.raw_pre_reqs))

    def __repr__(self):
        title_msg = self.title if self.title else "Untitled"
        return "%s %s: %s" % (self.dept_code, self.number, title_msg)

    def __attrs(self):
        return (self.dept_code, self.number, self.title, self.raw_pre_reqs, self.original_description)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Course) and self.__attrs() == other.__attrs()

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__attrs())
```

A slightly more complicated type:

```
class DependencyArcTail(db.Model):
    ''' A list of courses that is a pre-req for something else '''
    courses = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    ''' a list of heads that reference this one '''
    forwardLinks = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "DepArcTail %d: courses='%s' forwardLinks='%s'" % (id(self), getReprOfKeys(self.courses), getIdOfKeys(self.forwardLinks))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, DependencyArcTail):
            return False

        for this_course in self.courses:
            if not (this_course in other.courses):
                return False

        for other_course in other.courses:
            if not (other_course in self.courses):
                return False

        return True

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((tuple(self.courses), tuple(self.forwardLinks)))
```

Everything look good?

**Updated to reflect @Alex's comments**

```
class DependencyArcTail(db.Model):
    ''' A list of courses that is a pre-req for something else '''
    courses = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    ''' a list of heads that reference this one '''
    forwardLinks = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "DepArcTail %d: courses='%s' forwardLinks='%s'" % (id(self), getReprOfKeys(self.courses), getIdOfKeys(self.forwardLinks))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, DependencyArcTail) and set(self.courses) == set(other.courses) and set(self.forwardLinks) == set(other.forwardLinks)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((tuple(self.courses), tuple(self.forwardLinks)))
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first one is fine.  The second one is problematic for two reasons:

1. there might be duplicates in `.courses`
2. two entities with identical `.courses` but different `.forwardLinks` would compare equal but have different hashes

I would fix the second one by making equality depend on both courses and forward links, but both changes to sets (hence no duplicates), and the same for hashing.  I.e.:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, DependencyArcTail):
        return False

    return (set(self.courses) == set(other.courses) and
            set(self.forwardLinks) == set(other.forwardLinks))

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((frozenset(self.courses), frozenset(self.forwardLinks)))
```

This of course is assuming that the forward links **are** crucial to an object's "real value", otherwise they should be omitted from both `__eq__` and `__hash__`.

**Edit**: removed from `__hash__` calls to `tuple` which were at best redundant (and possibly damaging, as suggested by a comment by @Mark [[tx!!!]]); changed `set` to `frozenset` in the hashing, as suggested by a comment by @Phillips [[tx!!!]].

Comment: @Alex: doesn't that hash depend on the order of the elements in `tuple(set(self.courses))`, which might be somewhat arbitrary?

Comment: @Mark, it's arbitrary but not capricious -- though I'm not 100% sure that arbitrarily shuffled lists with the same items would produce the same-ordered set (it may vary with versions of Python), so it's best to avoid the `tuple` calls I lazily left in -- let me edit accordingly, thanks.

Comment: I think you should use `frozenset` instead of  `set`, the latter being unhashable.

Comment: when you override equal to should not you recommend  the not equal to part be also overridden for consistent behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes ?

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes/25176504#25176504). Few points: 1. You should implement `__ne__` (and probably use [total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering). 2. When you don't know how to equal, you should return `NotImplemented`