# Comparing two objects

Tags: python

Is there any way to check if two objects have the same values, other than to iterate through their attributes and manually compare their values?

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Joe Kington's solutions works if there is a `__dict__` (some objects, including builtins, don't have one) and `__eq__` works for all values of both dicts (a badly written `__eq__` mayraise exceptions etc). But it is horribly unpythonic. It doesn't even handle nominal subtypes properly... much less structural subtypes (i.e. types that you can use in place/for duck-typing). **Do not do this.**

But usually you're better off with a hand-tailored `__eq__` method that only compares some attributes that are significant. E.g. Rational should only compare numerator and denominator, nothing more.

Comment: "some meaningless comparisions may raise exceptions": nope, this applies only to comparisons involving ordering -- checking if `a` equals `b` (i.e., `a==b`, expressed or implied) **never** causes exceptions (unless you deliberately code a weird class overriding `__eq__` for the sole purpose of causing such exceptions;-). IOW, comparison for equality / inequality is **never** "meaningless".

Comment: @Alex Or unless somebody else codes such a class. Badly written classes occur pretty frequently. But, delnan seemed to imply that some builtin types behaved this way, which is indeed incorrect.

Comment: objects with `__slots__` don't have `__dict__` either

Comment: The problem is that testing equality can be completely senseless, so it'd be responsible to raise exceptions in that case! I more than once cursed at Python for not raising anything in `func==42` when I actually wanted to write `func()==42`. But we can never do this, even when the test is meaningless, because we want `something in (True, len, object)` to work at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

To expound on delnan's answer:

```
_NOTFOUND = object()

class Rational(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        for attr in ['numerator', 'denominator']:
            v1, v2 = [getattr(obj, attr, _NOTFOUND) for obj in [self, other]]
            if v1 is _NOTFOUND or v2 is _NOTFOUND:
                return False
            elif v1 != v2:
                return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compare [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) directly.
Otherwise you have to define either your own rich comparisons `__eq__` and possibly `__ne__`
or your own `__cmp__`

see the [datamodel](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) for more info

Answer (score -3):

`object1.__dict__ == object2.__dict__` Should be all you need, I think...

Edit: `vars(object1) == vars(object2)` is perhaps a bit more pythonic, though @delnan makes a valid point about objects (e.g. `int`s) that don't have a `__dict__`.  I disagree that a custom `__eq__` is a better approach for simple cases, though... Sometimes it's not worth the effort to go beyond quick and dirty, if quick and dirty perfectly does what you need, i.m.h.o.

Comment: @Aaron, I'd agree that modifying `__dict__` directly is basically always wrong... I'd disagree that reading it directly is basically always wrong.  Perhaps `vars` is a bit clearer, though...

Comment: no, reading it is basically always wrong as well. It bypasses the descriptor protocol, not to mention it relies on an implementation detail.

Comment: @Aaron - True, I guess I didn't think far enough into it.

Comment: It also fails in the case of `__slots__`. `__slots__` shows that it's not just about implementation details of Python implementations, it's implementation details of objects within CPython. Accessing `__dict__` directly (or indirectly through `vars()`) is bad.