# Implementing object equality based on a string-valued key in the object's dictionary

Tags: python, oop

I have created a class.

```
class DictToObject(object):
    def __init__(self, entries): 
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

    def id(self):
        keyColumn = self['KEY_COL_TX']
        keyValue = self[keyColumn]
        return keyValue # a string
```

The instances of this class are to be considered equal if `o1.id()` equals `o2.id()`

But I dont think it is possible to create a unique integer for all string values, so I need some other way to compare object equality without using `__hash__()`

Comment: `def __eq__(self,other): return self.id() == other.id()`

Comment: `__hash__` is no use for equality anyway, as collisions are to be expected (in fact unavoidable for most objects).

Comment: You're class doesn't support `__getitem__` ...

Comment: I don't get why you want to "cast" the string to an integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)