# Keep only one element of each group of elements who match each other

Tags: python

Suppose I have an object of the structure:

```
class Obj:
  def match(other):
    return check_match(self, other)
```

For example, `check_match` could check for overlap or for equality or for "is friend".

Now I'll have a list of those objects:

```
objList = create_random_list_of_Obj()
```

Now, for each element which matches other elements, I d like to keep only one of those mutually matching elements.

Remark and clarification:
So far, the task is ambiguous: If A and B match, and B and C match, but A and C do not match, then we could keep A and C or we could keep B. It's not important, which decision the algorithm will take. **The important thing is, that there are no matching elements in the final list.**

Two questions:

- **What is the pythonic way to do so?**
- Does this problem have a name?

Answer (score 3):

### Regarding: What is the pythonic way to do so?

The pythonic way is to rename your `match` method to `__eq__`.

Then you can do things like `element in list` with your custom object.

A very pythonic way to make a list contain unique items is then:

```
uniques = list(set(list_with_duplicates))
```

**Edit:** `__ne__` is not needed and will default to `not __eq__()`

### Does this problem have a name?

One could look for "equivalence classes".

Some references:

- implementing `__eq__` in your own class: [Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)
- stdlib docs on `__eq__`: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**eq**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)
- how `element in list` works behind the scenes: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details

Comment: The idea with the set seems smart, at least for transitive a `match` (equality for example). I wonder what will happen, if `match` is not transitive: "is friend" for example. A can B friend with B, B can be friend with C, but A is not necessarily friend with C.

Comment: @Michael The setup with set and `__eq__` still works, it would make sure that you only have one of {A,B} and one of {B,C}, but would allow both {A,C}. The outcome is not deterministic then, since if you start with {A,B,C} you can end with {A,C} or {B}. But on the other hand your questions is not deterministic if "is friend" is not transitive.

Comment: I'm aware that the solution to the given task is not unique. Application will be the removal of overlapping objects (not transitive) as well as removal of equal elements in a list (transitive). The only constraint in both cases is the same: Have no matching pairs in the final list. But I see that the non-transitive case could be extended to a difficult task when more constraints would apply ("keep as many as possible", "loose no matching group"). Full-fledged graph theory problems...

Answer (score -2):

Python has a type of `contains` method that works with the following syntax: `if x in y:` Use it to determine if a list contains an obj

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d"]
b = ["c", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
c = []

for member in a:
  if member in b and member not in c:
    c.append(member)
```

Should result in `c = ["c", "d"]`

Comment: The way that you have interpreted this problem, there are better solutions. For instance, using set intersections, or a direct list comprehension.