# Elegant way to parse strings which contain lists generated with join() in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to find a general way of generating objects which can be converted to strings and back again using the [parse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) module. For example, for a class `StringyObject` whose instances have just two attributes `a` and `b`:

```
import parse

class StringyObject(object):
    fmt = "{a} {b}"

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fmt.format(a=self.a, b=self.b)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, string):
        result = parse.parse(cls.fmt, string)
        kwargs = result.named
        return cls(**kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return NotImplemented

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = StringyObject("foo", "bar")
    reconstructed_obj = StringyObject.parse(str(obj))
    assert reconstructed_obj == obj, "The reconstructed object should be equivalent to the original one."
```

The script consecutively calls the `__str__` instance method and the `parse` class method, and verifies that the resulting objects `obj` and `reconstructed_obj` are equivalent (defined here as being instances of the same class and having the same dictionaries; cf. [Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes/25176504)).

So far, so good, but I'd like to extend this method to attributes which are lists of variable length. For example, if `b` is a list, then I could do the following:

```
import parse

class StringyObject(object):
    fmt = "{a} {b}"
    separator = ", "

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        assert isinstance(b, list), "b should be a list."
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        b_string = self.separator.join(self.b)
        return self.fmt.format(a=self.a, b=b_string)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, string):
        result = parse.parse(cls.fmt, string)
        kwargs = result.named
        kwargs['b'] = kwargs['b'].split(cls.separator)
        return cls(**kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return NotImplemented

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = StringyObject("foo", ["bar1", "bar2"])
    reconstructed_obj = StringyObject.parse(str(obj))
    assert reconstructed_obj == obj, "The reconstructed object should be equivalent to the original object."
```

This still works for this example, but is less elegant because I start to have to use `join()` and `split()`, which is what I wanted to avoid by using `parse.parse`. Furthermore, if I add another attribute `c` which comes after `b` in the string representation, the parsing goes haywire:

```
class StringyObject(object):
    fmt = "{a} {b} {c}"
    separator = ", "

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        assert isinstance(b, list), "b should be a list."
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __str__(self):
        b_string = self.separator.join(self.b)
        return self.fmt.format(a=self.a, b=b_string, c=self.c)
```

Then running the script

```
obj = StringyObject("foo", ["bar1", "bar2"], "hello")
result = parse.parse(StringyObject.fmt, str(obj))
```

produces the wrong `Result` object:

```
<Result () {'a': 'foo', 'c': 'bar2 hello', 'b': 'bar1,'}>
```

What I would actually like to is implement a kind of 'sub-parser' for `b` which keeps on running as long as it can find a `separator`, and only then continues with parsing `c`. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: *contain lists generated with join() in Python* It is WRONG. `' '.join()` do not generate a list but a string from list

Comment: [Moinuddin Quadri](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2063361/moinuddin-quadri), a string cannot 'contain' a list in the Pythonic sense of the word, so what I mean in this context is a 'listing' or 'enumeration' such as "a, b, c" within a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the desired parsing result could be achieved by adding some 'fixed' characters (not just spaces) in the format string. For example, below I've put a pipe (`|`) between the `{b}` and `{c}`:

```
import parse

class StringyObject(object):
    fmt = "{a} {b} | {c}"
    separator = ", "

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        assert isinstance(b, list), "b should be a list."
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __str__(self):
        b_string = self.separator.join(self.b)
        return self.fmt.format(a=self.a, b=b_string, c=self.c)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, string):
        result = parse.parse(cls.fmt, string)
        kwargs = result.named
        kwargs['b'] = kwargs['b'].split(cls.separator)
        return cls(**kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return NotImplemented

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = StringyObject("foo", ["bar1", "bar2"], "hello")
    result = parse.parse(StringyObject.fmt, str(obj))
    print result

    reconstructed_obj = StringyObject.parse(str(obj))
    assert reconstructed_obj == obj, "The reconstructed object should be equivalent to the original object."
```

The printed `Result` is

```
<Result () {'a': 'foo', 'c': 'hello', 'b': 'bar1, bar2'}>
```

as desired. The `reconstructed_obj` is also equivalent to the original `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to look into using `ast.literal_eval`. This function is a safe eval of Python literal structures (ints, float, strings, lists, dicts...)

I wasn't able to get your examples to work using the `parse` library, but if you modify your format string slightly, it will work pretty easily with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

class StringyObject(object):
    fmt = "{a!r}, {b!r}"

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fmt.format(a=self.a, b=self.b)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, string):
        return cls(*ast.literal_eval(string))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return NotImplemented

if __name__ == "__main__":
    objects = [("foo", "bar"), 
        ("foo", ["bar1", "bar2"]), 
        (["foo1", ("foo2", ["foo3", {"foo4"}])], {"bar1" : "bar2", "bar3": ["bar4", "bar5"]})]
    for a, b in objects:
        obj = StringyObject(a, b)
        reconstructed_obj = StringyObject.parse(str(obj))
        assert reconstructed_obj == obj, "The reconstructed object should be equivalent to the original one."
```

The downside to this implementation is that it will only work for basic python literals; i.e., `StringyObject(frozenset(['foo']), 'bar')` won't work.