# __eq__ method returns True for both == and > operators

Tags: python, comparison

I have declared a class `Triangle` in Python which takes base and height as `__init__` arguments and has a method `area` that computes and returns the area of the triangle. The `__eq__` method of the `Triangle` class compares the area of the triangles and return the value. The class is defined as below:

```
class Shape(object):
    def area(self):
        raise AttributeException("Subclasses should override this method.")

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        """
        base = base of the triangle.
        height = height of the triangle
        """
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
    def area(self):
        return (self.base * self.height)/2
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Triangle with base ' + str(self.base) + ' and height ' + str(self.height)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Two triangles are equal if their area is equal
        """
        return (self.area() == other.area())
```

Now I ran the program and created two instances to `Triangle` `t1` and `t3`, and gave them different base and height but their area is equal. So `t1 == t3` should be `True` which is returned as `True` only. But strangely, `t1 > t3` is also returned as `True`, which I don't understand why?

```
>>> t1 = Triangle(3,4)
>>> t3 = Triangle(2, 6)
>>> t1.area()
6
>>> t3.area()
6
>>> t1 == t3
True
>>> t1 > t3
True
>>> t1 < t3
False
>>>
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your class to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you implement `__gt__`?

Comment: Added the whole class. Its a simple learning example, I just defined __eq__.

Comment: I assume `__gt__` is defined in `Shape`

Comment: No Shape is a simple class inheriting Object and area method which does nothing but ask the child class to define area method. Added Shape as well.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem with the code you posted. I get a `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Triangle' and 'Triangle'`.

Comment: I don't get any error at all. I am using Python version 2.7.13. Are you using some other version?

Comment: Ah, that is the problem. I can reproduce it with Python 2.7, just not with Python 3. Investigating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I can't find a source on this, it seems as if Python 2 uses the `id` to compare two objects if you don't define the respective magic methods yourself.

Observe:

```
>>> t1 = Triangle(3, 4)
>>> t3 = Triangle(2, 6)
>>> t1 > t3
False
>>> t1 < t3
True
>>> t1 = Triangle(3, 4)
>>> t1 > t3
True
>>> t1 < t3
False
```

This behaviour isn't guaranteed as `id` doesn't promise you to assign increasing numbers to objects created later, but it does usually seem to work in CPython 2.7, since `id` will give you the physical address of the object.

You will observe that before the redefinition of `t1`, `id(t1) < id(t3)`, while afterwards, the opposite is the case.

Comment: You mean that in CPython, it is guaranteed that new objects are given increasing number, so it will be consistent in Cpython but not guaranteed in Python?

Comment: @GauravSachdeva No such thing is guaranteed. In CPython, `id` is the physical address of the object. It can be any address at which there is space available (usually, that gives increasing numbers in the beginning...)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

> If no __cmp__(), __eq__() or __ne__() operation is defined, class
>   instances are compared by object identity (“address”).

Also stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25176504), the newer versions of python 2 default uses the object's id for comparison.

So you should always define either `__gt__` or `__lt__` alongside of `__eq__` for comparing the way you wanted. And if you want, you can also define `__le__`, `__ge__`, `__ne__`...

One simple thing you can change is:

```
class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        """
        base = base of the triangle.
        height = height of the triangle
        """
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
    def area(self):
        return (self.base * self.height)/2
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Triangle with base ' + str(self.base) + ' and height ' + str(self.height)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Two triangles are equal if their area is equal
        """
        return (self.area() == other.area())
    def __gt__(self, other):
        """
        This works for both greater than and less than
        """
        return (self.area() > other.area())
```

Comment: You probably want to define all of `__gt__`, `__lt__`, `__ge__`, `__le__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__` at the same time, or use [total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering). More importantly, you should always implement `__hash__` when you implement `__eq__`, or things (ike `dict`) will break unexpectedly.