# Shorten a chain of conditions

Tags: python

I have a long condition which makes it possible to check if a field has been modified in order to call a function :

```
    if self.half_pension or not self.half_pension or self.half_pension_occasional \
        or not self.half_pension_occasional or self.half_pension_id != self._origin.half_pension_id \
        or self.half_pension_begin_date != self._origin.half_pension_begin_date \
        or self.half_pension_end_date != self._origin.half_pension_end_date \
        or self.half_pension_monday != self._origin.half_pension_monday \
        or self.half_pension_tuesday != self._origin.half_pension_tuesday \
        or self.half_pension_thursday != self._origin.half_pension_thursday \
        or self.half_pension_friday != self._origin.half_pension_friday \
        or self.half_pension_responsible_partner != self._origin.half_pension_responsible_partner:
            monstringxmlhalfpension = self.get_data_xml_for_halfpension(idUsager)
            resp_halfpension = c.service.XmlAjouterUnEvenement(Synchrone=1, donneesXml=monstringxmlhalfpension)
```

This is meant to be used within Odoo 10.

Is there a way to shorten this condition? Thank you

Comment: try splitting it to several boolean variables, then write your variable names instead of the conditions

Comment: Do you have a example ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that these conditions are always true:

```
if self.half_pension or not self.half_pension \
   or self.half_pension_occasional or not self.half_pension_occasional
```

A boolean value is either true or false, so the expression above is a tautology: a condition that's *always* true. To put it another way: there is no way for the `if` statement in the question to be false.

Also, notice that a condition for `self.half_pension_wednesday` is missing, I don't know if that's intentional.

Having said that - you seem to be comparing all the fields in an object, how about overriding `__eq__` and `__ne__` so two objects are equal if and only if all of the fields you're interested in are the same? and conversely, they're different if just one of the fields is different. With that, your condition can be as simple as:

```
if self != self._origin:
```

Comment: Sorry, i have a test with self != self._origin but don't works. I have a error :     if self.half_pension and self != self._origin:
AttributeError: 'ecole.partner.school' object has no attribute '_origin'

Comment: First you have to _override_ `__eq__` and `__ne__`, it's not as simple as writing `self != self._origin`. Second, make sure you're in the right object, if it complains of not finding `_origin` is because you're in an incorrect place.

Comment: This should get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes

Comment: Also, it's impossible to help you more without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can't reproduce your error, so I cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering this:

```
self.SOMETHING1 != self._origin.SOMETHING1 
or self.SOMETHING2 != self._origin.SOMETHING2
or self.SOMETHING3 != self._origin.SOMETHING3
```

it can be shortened by using `getattr`:

```
attrs = ['SOMETHING1', 'SOMETHING2', 'SOMETHING3']
any(getattr(self, attr) != getattr(self._origin, attr) for attr in attrs)
```

Of course, you could also create your `attrs` dynamically, e.g. by using:

```
attrs = [attr for attr in dir(self) if attr.startswith('half_pension')]
```

or something along these lines. You have to walk the extra mile yourself since you did not provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we have no info on what is inside `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using boolean valiables instead:

```
begin_date_error = self.half_pension_begin_date != self._origin.half_pension_begin_date 
mond_error = self.half_pension_monday != self._origin.half_pension_monday
```

etc.

You can even agregate some of your or conditions if needed (remenber, 'or'is associative) , like :

```
week_error = mond_error or tue_error or wed_error or thu_error or fri_error
```

etc.

This means that in the end, your condition will include these variable names and not whole conditions and will therefore be much shorter.