# How to check if some item properties already exist in list before appending

Tags: python

I have a class, and in a list I hold some instances of the class. Before appending a new instance I want to check if x, y are the same with some other item. 
If x,y exist already in another instance, I want to make another random pair. When I find a pair that is unique I will append the new instance to the list.

What is the most efficient way to check this by using only a list, and checking inside the for loop??

```
class Vehicle :
    def __init__(self, CoordX, CoordY, Z) :
        self.X=CoordX
        self.Y=CoordY
        self.Z=Z
VehicleList=[]
for i in range (1,15+1):
        obj_x = randint(1,30)
        obj_y = randint (1,20)
        obj_z=randint(1,100)
        If..#Check if [x,y] of item exists in list and Generate new random
        else:
        NewVehicle=Vehicle(obj_x,obj_y,obj_z)

        VehicleList.append(NewVehicle)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `__eq__` method for your class `Vehicle`

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, CoordX, CoordY, Z) :
        self.X = CoordX
        self.Y = CoordY
        self.Z = Z

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.X == other.X and self.Y == other.Y and self.Z == other.Z
```

Then check

```
if NewVehicle not in VehicleList:
    VehicleList.append(NewVehicle)
```

Related : [Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for example like this:

```
from random import randint

class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, CoordX, CoordY, Z) :
        self.X = CoordX
        self.Y = CoordY
        self.Z = Z

VehicleList=[]
for i in range (1, 15 + 1):
    obj_x = randint(1, 30)
    obj_y = randint(1, 20)
    obj_z = randint(1, 100)
    while any(v.X == obj_x and v.Y == obj_y and v.Z == obj_z for v in VehicleList):
        obj_x = randint(1, 30)
        obj_y = randint(1, 20)
        obj_z = randint(1, 100)
    NewVehicle = Vehicle(obj_x, obj_y, obj_z)
    VehicleList.append(NewVehicle)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the next() function ...

```
if next( (True for obj in VehiculeList if obj.x == obj_x and obj.y == obj_y), False):
    ... the list already contains x,y ...
```