# Foobar - Test cases not passing - Disorderly escape

Tags: python, math, factorial, fractions

0/10 test cases are passing.

Here is the challenge description:

(to keep formatting nice - i put the description in a paste bin)
Link to challenge description: https://pastebin.com/UQM4Hip9

Here is my trial code - PYTHON -  (0/10 test cases passed)

```
from math import factorial
from collections import Counter
from fractions import gcd

def cycle_count(c, n):
    cc=factorial(n)
    for a, b in Counter(c).items():
        cc//=(a**b)*factorial(b)
    return cc        

def cycle_partitions(n, i=1):
    yield [n]
    for i in range(i, n//2 + 1):
        for p in cycle_partitions(n-i, i):
            yield [i] + p

def solution(w, h, s):    
    grid=0
    for cpw in cycle_partitions(w):
        for cph in cycle_partitions(h):            
            m=cycle_count(cpw, w)*cycle_count(cph, h)
            grid+=m*(s**sum([sum([gcd(i, j) for i in cpw]) for j in cph]))

    return grid//(factorial(w)*factorial(h))

print(solution(2, 2, 2)) #Outputs 7
```

This code works in my python compiler on my computer but not on the foobar challenge??

Am I losing accuracy or something?

Answer (score 2):

**NOT HELPFUL**

Just a guess: wrong types of the return values of the functions? str vs. int?

**Improved Answer**

First a more detailed explanation for the 'type of values' thing:

In python, values are typed also if you do not have to declare a type. E.g.:

```
>>> i = 7
>>> s = '7'
>>> print(i, s, type(i), type(s), i == s)
7 7 <class 'int'> <class 'str'> False
```

I do not know the exact tests that are applied to the code, but typically those involve some equality test with `==`. If the type of the expected value and those value returned does not match, the equality fails. Perhaps [Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes) might help.

The instruction to the challenge (see pastebin) also explicitly mentions the expected return types: the returned values must be string (see line 41 / 47).

In addtion, the instruction also states that one should 'write a function answer(w, h, s)' (line 6). The posted solution implements a function `solution`.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck on this problem. 
The error is because of data type mismatch i.e your function returns an integer but the question specifically asked for a string.

Wrapping the return statement in str() will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is an integer. Convert it to a string, and it will work.

```
return str(grid//(factorial(w)*factorial(h)))
```