# Unsupported operand type(s) and unorderable types Error python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, typeerror

So I made a class with different attributes and when I want to multiply them or add or see if they are equal it returns a type error. The error says

> TypeError: unorderable types: method() <= method()
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'int'

```
def __init__(self, width, height):
    """
    Initializes a rectangular room with the specified width and height.

    Initially, no tiles in the room have been cleaned.

    width: an integer > 0
    height: an integer > 0
    """
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.tiles = {}
    for x in range(self.width):
        for y in range(self.height):
            self.tiles[(x, y)] = False #False means dirty and True means clean

def getHeight (self):
    return self.height

def getWidth (self):
    return self.width

def getTile (self, x, y):
    return self.tiles[(x, y)]
```

and when I call these parts of the class it returns the errors

```
def getRandomPosition(self):
    """
    Return a random position inside the room.

    returns: a Position object.
    """
    Position(random.randint(0, self.getWidth), random.randint(0, self.getHeight))

def isPositionInRoom(self, pos):
    """
    Return True if pos is inside the room.

    pos: a Position object.
    returns: True if pos is in the room, False otherwise.
    """
    if pos.getX <= self.getWidth and pos.getY <= self.getHeight:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: [elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes) and [object.__le__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__le__) might help

Comment: Add parentheses - your `getSomething` methods are methods, not values, so it should be `self.getSomething()`

Comment: `if pos.getX <= self.width and pos.getY <= self.height:`  - why create getters - use the atttributes themself - getters need to be called().