# Is there a magic method for sets in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a custom object like this:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I want it to work with sets according to the rule: **if objects have the same `x` they are equal**.

```
s = set()
s.add(MyObject(1, 2))

print(MyObject(1, 3) in s)  # It is False. I want it to be True, because `x = 1` for both.
```

Is there a magic method I could implement in `MyObject` to reach my purpose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `__eq__(self, other)`
- `__hash__(self)`

See https://hynek.me/articles/hashes-and-equality/ for more

Comment: Do I need both methods to be implemented or one of them?

Comment: both methods have to be implemented. (but you better read about it in order to understand why)

Comment: @Fomalhaut I think `__hash__` is  for getting the [underlaying hash table slot](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L72) and `__eq__` for [comparing the entries](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L83)