# How to compare two instances in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance, instance-variables

Is there possibility to compare two 'instances'? I have one variable and one list. Variable have type 'instance', items in list have also the same type. When I compare variable with the same item in list:

```
cities = [USA, Poland, England, GB, Italy]
variable = Italy

variable == cities[-1]
```

I received 'False' as output. I'm 100% sure that both elements are the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would need more details here, what is `variable`? What are the context of `list`? You'll likely need to [implement `__eq__` for your class to compare for semantic equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes).

Comment: `list` is a saved namespace, don't use it for variable names.

Comment: Try doing  'isinstance(variable, list)' and see if it returns True.

Comment: @BobbyTrap is was just example, I know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of objects in Python. Mutable, and immutable.

#### Immutable

- State cannot be changed.
- Usually thought of as "primitive" types.
- `int`, `float`, `string`, `tuple`, etc.

#### Mutable

- State can be updated and changed.
- `list`, `dict`, `set`, `bytearray`, any object that is created via the `class` token.

---

Depending on the type that you are discussing when you say `variable` this will affect the operator `==`. Immutable types will always be checked against the actual value (e.g. `1 == 1` is `True`), where mutable types are checked against the object's [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method (which overloads the `==` sign).

All of the mutable types listed - except new objects initialized with `class` - have a built-in `__eq__` methods that are used when the `==` sign is present. Assuming you are using your own object, take the following for example:

```py
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.integer = integer

print(Obj(1) == Obj(1)) # False
```

Notice that despite `integer` being equal for each `Obj`, due to the fact `Obj` is a mutable type without the `__eq__` method Python will check if the objects are equal to each other based on their space in memory- in other words, for it to be `True`, the object must be the exact same one you initialized.

```py
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.integer = integer

obj = Obj(1)

print(obj == obj)  # True
```

To manually overload the `==` sign, you must use the `__eq__` method:

```py
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.integer = integer

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # Comparison of two integers.
        return self.integer == other.integer

print(Obj(1) == Obj(1))  # True
```

Comment: How to implement it for string?

Comment: Strings already have a built-in `__eq__` method. If you receiving a `False` when doing comparison, it means that they are different. `"hello world" == "helloworld"` will return `False`.

Comment: I'm asking because my problem concerns strings. Is there any solution?

Comment: You would have to format the string in the manner where the ones that are suppose to be equal to each other are indeed equal (e.g. translating things like `à` to `a`, defaulting to lowercase or uppercase, etc.) The fact is, if Python is telling you two strings are unequal, it means that the strings are simply unequal (`"hello" == "Hello"` yields `False`, `"héllo" == "hello"` yields `False`.)

Comment: Yes yes but my strings are the same, I'm sure of that. Main cause of problem is 'instance' type but as you mentioned before, string already have __eq__ so now, Ikd how to solve it.

Comment: To better help you I would advise you editing your original post with what the values of `variable` and `list`. Without those two things there is no way I can help you further - and not because I don't want to, but because it's impossible without the context.

Comment: You can take anything you want but it must be string. I also edited my post.

Comment: `["USA", "Poland", "England", "GB", "Italy"][-1] == "Italy` returns `True` for me. Your example doesn't seem to reflect what is going on. If basic equalities like this didn't work the world as we know would burn!