# Comparing of elements in deque in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, binary-tree, deque

Can someone explain me, how works comparing of tree nodes in deque. For example, I pushed two children of two same binary trees in two different deques and I got `deque1 = deque([TreeNode{val: 2, left: None, right: None}, TreeNode{val: 3, left: None, right: None}])`, `deque2 = deque([TreeNode{val: 2, left: None, right: None}, TreeNode{val: 3, left: None, right: None}])`, but when I compared them, I got `False`. Why if two deques includes same nodes they are not equal? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in thinking that if your `deque` objects contained equal objects then the two `deque` instances would also evaluate to be equal. The problem you are running into is that complex objects, like instances of `TreeNode`, by default are equal only if they are the same object, not necessarily if they have have the same contents. Here is a simplified example:

```
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self,val, left, right):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        
t1 = TreeNode(2, None, None)
t2 = TreeNode(2, None, None)

print(t1 == t2)
print(t1 == t1)
```

```
False
True
```

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes) for some tips on how to work around the issue.