# Change array attribute

Tags: python, matrix, dtype

I need to compare two matrices, built using two different functions.

```
a=csr_matrix(M) (scipy function)
b=SparseMatrix(M) (My own function)
```

If I print 'a' and 'b' I get:

```
[[10. 20.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 30. 99. 40.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 50. 60. 70.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 80.]]
[[10. 20.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. 30. 99. 40.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. 50. 60. 70.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 80.]]
```

ie. the identical matrix.

BUT!: If I do

```
print(a==b)
```

it returns 'false'

Now,

```
print(a.dtype) = float64 
print(b.dtype) = 'SparseMatrix' object has no attribute 'dtype'.
```

I'm guessing this difference in regard to the type is the reason the boolean returns false?

Is there a smooth way to overcome this problem? - Preferably without changing 'SparseMatrix'.

Edit: Here is 'SparseMatrix':

```
class SparseMatrix:
    
    def __init__(self, A, tol = 1e-8):
        """
        

        Parameters
        ----------
        A : Numpy.Array
            Input matrix.
        tol : float, optional
            Tolerance for what is to be considered equal to 0. The default is 1e-8.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        self.n_rows = A.shape[0]
        self.n_cols = A.shape[1]
        self.intern_represent = 'CSR'
        self.tol = tol
        self.V = []
        self.col_index = [] 
        self.row_index = zeros(self.n_rows + 1, dtype = int) 
        self.number_of_nonzero = 0
        
        for row in range(self.n_rows):
            self.row_index[row] = self.number_of_nonzero 
            for column in range(self.n_cols):
                if abs(A[row, column]) >= tol:
                    self.number_of_nonzero += 1
                    self.V.append(A[row, column])
                    self.col_index.append(column)
        self.row_index[-1] = self.number_of_nonzero
```

Comment: Can we see `SparseMatrix`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason `a==b` is `False` is because `a` and `b` are clearly different things. Yes, they might contain all the same values. However, everything else about them is different: One is a scipy `csr_matrix` and the other is a custom object, an instance of `SparseMatrix` that you wrote yourself. They are completely different objects, with a different underlying structure, different variables and methods, different data structure, and exist in different parts of the computer's memory.

The documentation on [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) such as the `==` operator tells us that:

> The default behavior for equality comparison (== and !=) is based on the identity of the objects. Hence, **equality comparison of instances with the same identity results in equality, and equality comparison of instances with different identities results in inequality.**

What this says is that, for arbitrary objects (i.e. not special types like numbers) `==` will only be `True` if you are comparing *the same object to itself*. Like doing `a==a` or `b==b`. It goes on to say:

> The behavior of the default equality comparison, that instances with different identities are always unequal, may be in contrast to what types will need that have a sensible definition of object value and value-based equality. **Such types will need to customize their comparison behavior, and in fact, a number of built-in types have done that.**

I.e. for custom classes/objects, the only way for `==` to work is if the creator of the class (you) *teaches* python how to compare it to other things.

There lies your solution of what to do. If you want the class you have created, `SparseMatrix`, to be able to be compared with a `csr_matrix`, you need to implement that yourself.

The way to do this is by implementing specially-named methods in your `SparseMatrix` class, such as `__eq__`. You can look at the [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes) as well as the documentation or some tutorials.

As an example:

```
class SparseMatrix:

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # When we are comparing with numpy arrays:
        if isinstance(other, np.array):

            # The dimensions have to be the same
            if other.shape[0] != self.n_rows or other.shape[1] != self.n_cols:
                return False
            
            # And the values have to be all the same
            # Return False the first time we find an unequal value
            for row in range(self.n_rows):
                for col in range(self.n_cols):
                    if self.V[row, col] != other[row, col]:
                        return False
            return True
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, immensely grateful.
I was trying out this as a way of testing my function, but I see now that there is the assertEqual command, typically run in a test class. Will that approach be less sensitive to type differences? (In any case, I suppose I could use the approach outlined in the post you linked in a test class as well.)

Comment: @Bronze Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.debug). `assertEqual` just checks whether `a == b` as normal, the same rules apply. If my answer has resolved your query, be sure to [mark it as Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how your custom function constructed the matrix. For, `csr_matrix` creates a **matrix object** which has a `dtype` property. If your function operates by constructing a three-dimensional array, for example, that resembles a sparse matrix, then that means that they are different types of objects.

You can check if they are of the same type by using `print(type(a))` and `print(type(a))`. I would check that first and then proceed in comparing them not by their properties, which they obviously don't share, but by a for loop of their content (probably using the `all()` function).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most effective solution, but I would just use a for loop on both matrixes and compare them to each other.