# Item still append to list even though there is the same item in the list

Tags: python

```
class Amenity():
  def __init__(self, itemCode, description, price):
    self._itemCode = itemCode
    self._description = description
    self._price = price

  def __str__(self):
    return "{}, {}, ${:.2f}".format(self._itemCode, self._description, self._price)

class Room():
  def __init__(self):
    self._amenities = []

  def addAmenity(self, newItem):
    if newItem in self._amenities:
      return "Duplicate found"
    else:
        self._amenities.append(newItem)

  def __str__(self):
    amenityListing = "\n".join(str(amenity) for amenity in self._amenities)
    return "{} ".format(amenityListing)

def main():
    room2 = Room()
    room2Amenity1 = Amenity("GYM-PEP","Per entry pass to gym (Level 4-01)",1.00)
    room2Amenity2 = Amenity("FRIDGE","Mini Fridge (50L)",4.59)
    room2Amenity3 = Amenity("WI-FI","One-day Wi-Fi access",1.00)
    room2Amenity4 = Amenity("GYM-PEP","Per entry pass to gym (Level 4-01)",1.00)
    room2.addAmenity(room2Amenity1)
    room2.addAmenity(room2Amenity2)
    room2.addAmenity(room2Amenity3)
    print(room2)
    print()
    room2.addAmenity(room2Amenity4)
    print(room2)
```

**Output**

GYM-PEP, Per entry pass to gym (Level 4-01), $1.00
FRIDGE, Mini Fridge (50L), $4.59
WI-FI, One-day Wi-Fi access, $1.00

GYM-PEP, Per entry pass to gym (Level 4-01), $1.00
FRIDGE, Mini Fridge (50L), $4.59
WI-FI, One-day Wi-Fi access, $1.00
GYM-PEP, Per entry pass to gym (Level 4-01), $1.00

**Expected Output**

GYM-PEP, Per entry pass to gym (Level 4-01), $1.00
FRIDGE, Mini Fridge (50L), $4.59
WI-FI, One-day Wi-Fi access, $1.00

GYM-PEP, Per entry pass to gym (Level 4-01), $1.00
FRIDGE, Mini Fridge (50L), $4.59
WI-FI, One-day Wi-Fi access, $1.00
Duplicate found

Comment: `room2Amenity1` is not the same object as `room2Amenity4`, so it's not going to be found by `in`.  If you add `room2Amenity1` again, it will work as you expect.

Comment: You probably want to [override `__eq__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390250/elegant-ways-to-support-equivalence-equality-in-python-classes)

Comment: `room2Amenity1 != room2Amenity4`

Comment: If you don't need to print the error message, you might consider using a `set` rather than a `list`. But you'll still need to deal with the equality issue.

Answer (score 1):

When the `in` operator searches the list, what it actually does behind the scenes is look for any object in the list that is *equal to* the object you ask it to look for. The default "equality" for objects in python is their `id`, an effectively arbitrary value that's different for each instance. Two instances of the class will have different `id`s, even if all of their attributes are equal. That's what's happening here - your two equal objects are still getting treated as different objects.

You can define your own "equality" for your custom classes by overriding the `__eq__()` method:

```
class Amenity():
  ...
  def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Amenity):
      return (self._itemCode, self._description, self._price) == (other._itemCode, other._description, other._price)
      # alternatively, less verbose: return str(self) == str(other)
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: Generally it is better practice to `return NotImplemented` in the `else`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `room2Amenity4` is not the same object as `room2Amenity1`. They are separate objects.

The `self._amenities = []` list in `room2Amenity4` only has one value, so, `addAmenity` doesn't print `Duplicate found`.

If you try to add `room2.addAmenity(room2Amenity1)` again, then the `self._amenities = []` list in `room2Amenity1` will have two same values, then `addAmenity` function will print `Duplicate found`.

To solve the problem, you can use the following code in your `Amenity` class:

```
class Amenity():
  def __init__(self, itemCode, description, price):
    self._itemCode = itemCode
    self._description = description
    self._price = price

  def __str__(self):
    return "{}, {}, ${:.2f}".format(self._itemCode, self._description, self._price)

  #Override the __eq__ function
  def __eq__(self, other_object):
    #Check if two same values are passed to two objects
    if isinstance(other_object, Amenity):
      return (self._itemCode, self._description, self._price) == (other_object._itemCode, other_object._description, oother_objectther._price) 

    else:
      return NotImplemented
```

In the above code, we have overriden the **eq** function to check if values passed to different objects are equal.

Comment: You've identified the issue, but how can the OP _resolve_ this?

Comment: I would suggest simply: `return isinstance(other_object, Amenity) and self._itemCode == other_object._itemCode and ...`

Comment: So, it is usually better practice to `return NotImplemented` in the else clause here